# Replace strings from text file with csv values

Tags: grep, sed, csv, find-and-replace

I've got a txt file (`template.txt`) with stuff like:

```
Hostname from Client: !hostname . OS !windowsversion
```

and a CSV-Export from many clients:

```
!hostname, !windowsversion
exampleName, Windows10-Pro
```

I'm just looking for a solution to replace the values(!) from `template.txt` with the columns/values from my CSV.

The CSV-File contains many rows of client information and I need to put it in my `template.txt` file. I don't want to do it 200 times manually.

So my goal is to convert the `template.txt` file to the following output:

```
Hostname from Client: exampleName . OS Windows10-Pro
```

Is there any option to automate it? I'm just thinking about using `sed` with regex and `grep` or something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give better examples of the data and the wanted result and your operating system.

Comment: (1) It looks like there is exactly one line in `template.txt` and many lines in the CSV file. Please confirm. (2) Do you want a generic solution designed to work with any template? Or can we hardcode the logic of the specific template in question and only process the CSV? The latter is simpler. If it's a one-time task then the former would be an overkill. (3) What is your OS? (4) What have you tried so far?

Comment: (5) If it's CSV then there is a leading space before `Windows10-Pro` and it *belongs to the value*. In the template there is one space before `!windowsversion` and it belongs to the template. In the desired output there is one space before `Windows10-Pro`. This doesn't fit. Which space did you omit and why? (6) `sed` or `grep` you mentioned are not well equipped to handle quoting in CSV easily. Can we assume all the values in your CSV are without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python to import CSV values into a template text file `template.txt`:

```
from csv import reader, writer
with open("csv-export.csv") as f, open("template.txt", 'w') as g:
    reader_obj = reader(f)
    writer_obj = writer(g)
    # Skip header row.
    next(reader_obj)
    for row in reader_obj:
        writer_obj.writerow([f'Hostname from Client: {row[0]} . OS{row[1]}'])
```

Sample output in `template.txt`:

```
Hostname from Client: exampleName . OS Windows10-Pro
Hostname from Client: 2ndname . OS Windows-8
Hostname from Client: 3rdname . OS Windows-XP
```